# Is there a way for an application to remain on a specific workspace?

Tags: applications, workspace

I have a workspace layout, where several apps are opened in different workspaces in a full-screen mode. I got used to this layout and remember corresponding numbers, so it is very fast to switch between full-screen apps just by pressing Win+num.
However, if I close an app in any workspace and it becomes empty, all other apps opened in other following workspaces shift left to that available workspace and their corresponding workspace numbers change as well. This is very annoying. Is there a way to stick an app to a specific workspace, so if a workspace becomes empty it remains empty?

PS: On macOS one can assign a specific workspace to an app, so then you run it - it is opened in that workspace automatically and stays there, which is a bliss to implement in eOS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a solution - Dynamic Workspaces must be disabled in GNOME settings:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior dynamic-workspaces false
```

Now the empty workspace is not removed from a workspace chain.